# Installing fftw--Unable to guess build type

Tags: linux, cygwin, fftw

I'm trying to install FFTW and when I get to the `./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float` command and when I run it, this is the error I get. How do I overcome this? I'm in Cygwin on windows 10 if that helps.

```
$ ./configure checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build environment is sane... yes checking for gawk... gawk checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes checking type prefix for installed files... (none) checking for vendor's cc to be used instead of gcc... checking for cc... cc checking for C compiler default output... a.exe checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of executables... .exe checking for suffix of object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking whether cc accepts -g... yes checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed checking for style of include used by make... GNU checking dependency style of cc... gcc3 checking whether we are using gcc 2.90 or later... yes checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes checking for ranlib... ranlib checking whether ln -s works... yes checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2003-02-22, has failed to recognize the operating system you are using. It is advised that you download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

    ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please send the following data and any information you think might be pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2003-02-22

uname -m = x86_64 uname -r = 3.1.2(0.340/5/3) uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-10.0 uname -v = 2019-12-21 15:25

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown /bin/uname -X     =

hostinfo               = /bin/universe          = /usr/bin/arch -k    
= /bin/arch              = x86_64 /usr/bin/oslevel       = /usr/convex/getsysinfo =

UNAME_MACHINE = x86_64 UNAME_RELEASE = 3.1.2(0.340/5/3) UNAME_SYSTEM 
= CYGWIN_NT-10.0 UNAME_VERSION = 2019-12-21 15:25 configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one

configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

I now Get the error:

I now get the error:

```
> mpicc    main.o  run.o  predict.o begrun.o endrun.o global.o
> timestep.o  init.o restart.o  io.o accel.o   read_ic.o  ngb.o system.o
> allocate.o  density.o gravtree.o hydra.o  driftfac.o domain.o 
> allvars.o potential.o forcetree.o   peano.o gravtree_forcetest.o
> pm_periodic.o pm_nonperiodic.o longrange.o   -g  -L/usr/lib 
> -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/usr/local/lib -lsrfftw_mpi -lsfftw_mpi -lsrfftw -lsfftw    -o  Gadget2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
> cannot find -lsrfftw_mpi
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
> cannot find -lsfftw_mpi collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:243: Gadget2] Error 1
```

Comment: fftw3 package is already available in Cygwin. Any reason why you need a mpi version ?

Comment: In general it is a usual practice for building Cygwin package to run `autoreconf` before `configure` . The current Cygwin package is built in that way if you look on the Cygwin source package of `fftw3`.

Comment: Hi, I'm following the instructions to get Gadget2 code running using Cygwin. I can't get past the error.

Comment: It seems Gadget2 is aged. It is from 2005 and requires fftw version2.  that on its own website `FFTW 2.1.5 is the stable release of FFTW2, last updated in 1999. FFTW 2.1.5 is obsolete, but because its API is incompatible with that of version 3.x, we continue to distribute it for those users who require backwards compatibility. `

Comment: I tried to use that version and I still get stuck on that error :(

Comment: Okay--it turns out I may not have installed openmpi. Might that have been the problem?

Comment: install `libopenmpi-devel` and  `libhdf5-devel`

Comment: As an aside, what is the meaning of make: *** [Makefile:1879: install-recursive] Error 1

?

Answer (score 1):

fftw-2.1.5 is so old that it requires a suggestion to properly configure under a recent Cygwin.

```
$ ./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float  --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
....
config.status: creating mpi/Makefile
config.status: creating fftw.spec
config.status: creating fftw/config.h
config.status: creating fftw/fftw.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

I will not bet that you will have clean run with MPI and HDF5 as they also are more recent than those tested on Gadget2